# second monitor causes graphics suttering

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, graphics

I'm running HP Probook 450 with Windows 8.1 - 64bit.

When I connect a second monitor (Philips 234cl) to the HDMI port, the laptop monitor stutters every 15 seconds or so. The newly connected monitor displays 'no video input' and then goes to sleep.

This exact same setup has worked flawlessly for a few weeks but the problem has only appeared this morning.

Comment: I have seen a feature like 'changing display between different monitors or projectors' in some laptops. I don't know what its actually called. Probably one of the Function keys is used for that purpose. Did your's have a feature or settings like that ?

Comment: The only monitor-related function key does the same thing as win+p
 - the extend/duplicate menu

Comment: What option did you choose in it ?

Comment: i tried all of them, stuttering continues, picking duplicate sets the laptop screen to 4:3 even though the second monitor is 16:9

Comment: Are you sure that the HDMI port and cable is complaint free ?

Comment: ok so this is weird - I just unplugged the HDMI cable out and plugged it back in (for the fourth or fifth time) and the issue is gone - both monitors are working fine at the correct resolutions, 
I don't know what caused the problem or what solved it, but it's gone.

Comment: May be you didn't inserted the cable well. The second monitor goes to sleep when it losses signal from the port.